# Pandas - Conditional grouping

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, conditional-statements

I have the following DataFrame containing employment history:
(1900-01-01 is used to store a null end date)

| id | company | job_title | start_date | end_date | is_current_employer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Google | Manager | 2023-05-06 | 1900-01-01 | 1 |
| A | Amazon | SWE | 2021-01-19 | 2023-02-02 | 0 |
| A | Meta | SWE | 2017-11-13 | 2020-10-24 | 0 |
| B | Tesla | Research | 2020-06-06 | 2023-07-14 | 0 |
| B | Microsoft | Data Eng. | 2017-04-17 | 2019-12-05 | 0 |
| C | Adobe | Intern | 2022-10-12 | 1900-01-01 | 1 |
| C | TikTok | Intern | 2023-03-23 | 1900-01-01 | 1 |

I'm hoping to return a DataFrame with one record for each ID, with that ID's most recent employment, like so:

| id | company | job_title | start_date | end_date | is_current_employer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Google | Manager | 2023-05-06 | 1900-01-01 | 1 |
| B | Tesla | Research | 2020-06-06 | 2023-07-14 | 0 |
| C | Adobe | Intern | 2022-10-12 | 1900-01-01 | 1 |

If a candidate (ID) has only one current employer, that record should be returned.
If a candidate has no current employers, the most recent employer should be returned (max start date).
If a candidate has multiple current employers, the record with the earlier start date should be returned.

How can I concisely do this in Python?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask], which has tips like how to write a good title. A good title helps attract people and helps them more quickly understand what you're asking.

Comment: *"1900-01-01 is used to store a null end date"* -- Beside the point, but is it possible to avoid doing that, and use `NaT` instead?

Comment: You can get the result you want here by just getting the max start date per group, but I think the edge case you're concerned about isn't actually represented here: when a candidate started and ended at one employer while working for another one.

Comment: *"If a candidate has multiple current employers, the record with the earlier start date should be returned."* -- You mean the *later* start date, right? That's what you're showing for C.

Comment: Yes, edited my original post--I'm looking for the earlier start date, since I want the job they've been at longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use group by and first() to do this. First, you must sort by start date to get the most recent employment:

```
df.sort_values(["start_date"], ascending=False).groupby("id").first()
```

Output:

| id | company | job_title | start_date | end_date | is_current_employer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Google | Manager | 2023-05-06 | 1900-01-01 | 1 |
| B | Tesla | Research | 2020-06-06 | 2023-07-14 | 0 |
| C | TikTok | Intern | 2023-03-23 | 1900-01-01 | 1 |

Comment: `C  Adobe` vs `C  TikTok`?

Comment: @Vitalizzare OP edited the question

Comment: This worked! I mistyped my post originally (when there are two current employers, I want the earlier start date, not later) but this solution still works perfectly after sorting by end date.